# TweetInVi v2 .NET filtered stream

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tweetinvi

I don't know if I am bad at googling but I can't find anywhere the filtered stream documentation for the twitter api v2 (tweetInVi).

Comment: https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi/dist/streams-v1.1/filtered-stream.html

Comment: @MarkusMeyer correct me if I am wrong but that is for v1.1 not v2

Comment: as i see, they just wrote this one and that all, so. maybe, there`s internal changes and interface the same, https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi/dist/streams-v2/sample-stream.html

Comment: They don't I have tried it and it doesn't work. I can also see people on the libraries git hub page using: `StartFilteredStreamV2Parameters() `  [Link to example](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/1086). Which doesn't exist in that doc